# Change BigQuery project ID

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it somehow possible to change a project ID in BigQuery?
I am open to any solutions.

I do see an option for changing the project name in IAM & ADMIN but this does not apply when querying data.

```
SELECT * FROM [project_id:set.table]
```

In the query above I want to change the "project_id" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add to Mingyu answer - if you are using API or client other then Web UI - you can use  [defaultDataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.defaultDataset) property to specify the default dataset to use for unqualified table names in the query.
Meantime, there is no way to change project id of existing project rather than create new one, then copy needed datasets/tables to that new project (copying in free of charge) and finally delete tables in old project so you don't pay for extra storage

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change the project id. But in BigQuery UI, you can omit the "project_id:" part, and it will query the table in your current project.

Answer (score 1):

This an old question but maybe can help someone.
You can set @@dataset_project_id

```
SET @@dataset_project_id = 'MyProject';
```

Reference

> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/multi-statement-queries#set_system_variable